# simple android code to display cocos2d tile map

Tags: cocos2d-android

I want to develop tile map in my game application in cocos2d android, but I can't find any good and complete code for that. If there is any simple code to display the map please help me
thanks 
santanu

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine Supports Tile Map and pretty much mature applying physics Engine Laws as well.

You can start with this tutorial and there is also available tiled map tutorial on AndEngine.

http://www.andengine.org/blog/2010/06/andengine-getting-started-tutorial-video/